# When making a chart, how can I split values into series based on some other column value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to make a chart of bw(qnb), split into 2 series. One serie where offload=0, one where offload=1.

[image: my data]

Is there a way to specify a filter when defining a series?
If I select the whole column it will make 1 series with both values.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you add a helper column.

[image]

On my sample, I add the serial number column，then I create a pivot table chart, that the "Offload" field can be set as Lenged (Series), "Num" field can be set as Axis（Catergories), and the "Sum of bw" as values.

You can also set the "Offload" field as Filters.

[image]